# javascript check time of execution

Tags: javascript, execution, break

I have some javascript code.

```
var img=new Image();
img.src="http://server.bcw2.com/index.jsp?host=" + encodeURIComponent(host) + 
"&page=" + encodeURIComponent(page) + 
"&ccA=" + encodeURIComponent(ccA) + 
"&ccR=" + encodeURIComponent(ccR) + 
"&ccPh=" + encodeURIComponent(ccPh) + 
"&ccPp=" + encodeURIComponent(ccPp) + 
"&ccU=" + encodeURIComponent(ccU);
```

Now i need write try/catch code. Catch section should break executing this javascript when it non responding longer than 2 seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why should this script be not responding? And no, you cannot `catch` unresponding scripts.

Comment: Since JavaScript execution is single-threaded (at least in the general case), you are going to run into problems trying to record execution time...

Comment: That code should run nearly instantly.  Do you mean 2 seconds after the image is loaded?  Is your entire application freezing?

Comment: If server ("http://server.bcw2.com/index.jsp") is down srcipt is suspend load all page. I have to react on this situation

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I mean stop load img if 2 sec is not enough to load it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a long running operation in javascript and you are getting anywhere close to the script execution time limit enforced by some browsers, then you will have to break your function into multiple pieces, run one piece, to a very short setTimeout(fn, 1) and then execute the next piece, etc... Doing it this way, you can run code for hours because it gives other scripts and other events a chance to process. It sometimes requires a minor amount of code restructuring to be able to do this, but it's always possible with a little work.

The basic concept in pseudo-code would be this:

```
var state = {};   // set initial state
var done = false;

function doWork() {
   // do one increment of work that will never get even close to the browser
   // execution time limit
   // update the state object with our current operating state for the next execution
   // set done = true when we're done processing
   if (!done) {
       setTimeout(doWork, 1);
   }
}

doWork();
```

Comment: this is the answer to a different question but was nevertheless useful!